# How to encrypt and send data via ECDH, with only a publickey (peerkey) provided?

Tags: python, m2crypto, elliptic-curve

I'm coding a program that needs asymmetric cryptography. My approach is using Python's M2Crypto and I have chosen ECDH as the algorithm. However, I also want the procedure to be as simple as RSA, which requires only the public key of our receiver. ECDH is not. Its public key seems to have to be combined with a sender's own public key first, thus shared secret calculated and everything done.

Regardless of efficiency, I do want such a solution, so that if anyone wants to send me a message, my EC public key is published and the sender has to:

1. get his/her own EC private key
2. combine this private key with my public one and calculate a shared secret
3. use the secret and AES or other symmetric cipher encrypt the message
4. send me ciphertext and the derived public key(from this private key).

But here is a problem. I observed that a successful key exchange exists only when either side generate their keys basing on the same curve parameters. But unless I provide additional information of what curve my public key has based on, is there any other way of figuring this out? A public key is loaded with:

```
M2Crypto.EC.load_pub_key([filename])
```

And an EC.EC_pub instance is returned. I think information about the curve should hide somewhere in this instance, but I've not found where.

Please point out what I have missed, or if my solution was wrong or can be simpler, or any other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: (1) please provide us with the actual use case, "a program that needs asymmetric cryptography" *is not a use case* (2) please ask questions about cryptographic protocols in [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) (3) don't try to move cryptographic algorithms into spaces where they are not supposed to go; key agreement (DH) is not signing and vice versa, don't even compare them (4) yes, you need to use the same parameters, you might want to look into ephemeral-static DH.

Comment: Thanks for your advises. I want EC for both signing and encrypting, fortunately m2crypto provides ECDSA and ECDH and I think that's sufficient. I do need same parameters, I am now wondering how to find out this: which curve a key had based on, preferably in Python codes, just like running OpenSSL in shell using `openssl ec -param_out`.

Comment: There are different ways of encoding elliptic curve parameters. In X9.62 curves are represented by an ASN.1 structure, which can either not contain the parameters, it can contain a "named curve" in which an OID is used to represent the curve, or (and this is probably the most common one) it can contain the curve parameters encoded as ASN.1. Trick with the last one is that you probably need to verify the correctness of the key/parameters before using them. This is the trouble with ECC, it's way more complex than RSA.